# outputing a list to a file mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
ret = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length@x, i++, 
  AppendTo[ret, {idNum = x[[i, 1]] , a = x[[i, 2]], b = x[[i, 3]], 
     c = x[[i, 4]], d = x[[i, 5]], e = x[[i, 6]], f = x[[i, 7]], 
     g = DateDifference[{d, e, f}, {currYear, currMonth, currDay}], 
     If[g > 90, Y, N]}];];
Print@ret
```

How do i output a list in to text file which has no bracket and braces, also need new line after each line.

Comment: It would be nice if you could post a working code snippet....

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the command [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Export.html), eg to save an nxn array as comma separated values use something like:

```
data = RandomInteger[{0, 256}, {50, 50}]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "data.csv", data, "CSV"]
```

The built-in formats are given in [`$ExportFormats`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24ExportFormats.html)

Comment: [This guide page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html) has the formats listed by category.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `Export["ret.m", ret, "Lines"]` to get one entry per line in the output file `ret.m`.  YMMV depending on the structure of the stuff you're exporting.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a sidetalk:

The usual way to program in Mathematica is functional, rather than procedural.

Variables are defined only when you need to inspect something, or preserve results for future work. Also, loops are discouraged.

An equivalent form of your program (just a quick draft), in these lines may be something like:

```
x = {{1, a1, b1, c1, 2010, 11, 12},
     {1, a2, b2, c2, 2011, 12, 13}};
Export["c:\data.csv", #, "CSV"] &
[Flatten[
    {#[[1 ;; 7]],
     {#, If[# > 90, "Y", "N"]} &@
      DateDifference[#[[5 ;; 7]], DateList[][[1 ;; 3]]]}
    ] & /@ x]
```

Comment: just a nit.  Loops still occur, after all `Map` is a loop. But, explicitly controlled loops, like `For` and `Do`, are discouraged. One of the reasons why is that they require extra coding just to set up, i.e. you have to explicitly set up your starting and ending conditions, but with `Map`, `Fold`, and `Nest` no explicit reference to the length of the `List` (or other `Head`) need ever be referenced. (They work more in the sense of `ForEach` from other languages.) Also, they're semantic meaning is clearer, i.e. `Map` this function onto every element of this `List`.

Comment: @rcollyer Please feel free to update the answer. It was just intended to open the asker's mind to functional programming. But perhaps fell short.

Comment: still a ways to go for edit capabilities.  But, I don't think it missed, just slightly to the side.  I even gave it a +1.  As he didn't listen the first time ...